# Websocket connection terminates due to subprotocol mismatch

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, websocket

I am implementing a websocket client in C# for an existing websockocket server written in C++. The server uses two subprotocols: "mySubprotocolOne", "mySubProtocolTwo". I am not allowed to touch the server code.

To initiate the websocket connection I am using the following code:

```
var wsClient = new ClientWebSocket();
wsClient.Options.AddSubProtocol("mySubprotocolOne");
await wsClient.ConnectAsync(new Uri(wsUri), cToken);
```

I observed the following behavior with wireshark:

```
Client -> Server | HTTP | GET / HTTP/1.1
Server -> Client | HTTP | HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Client -> Server | TCP | [FIN, ACK]
Server -> Client | TCP | [ACK]
Server -> Client | TCP | [FIN, ACK]
```

The server is accepting the request but then my client instantly terminates the connection. On the client side I get the following exception:

> Could not establish websocket connection to host ws://ip:port/ - System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The WebSocket client request requested 'mySubprotocolOne' protocol(s), but server is only accepting 'mySubprotocolOne,mySubProtocolTwo' protocol(s)

The response header coming from the server looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n
Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n
Connection: Upgrade\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: someBase64Key\r\n
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: mySubprotocolOne,mySubProtocolTwo\r\n
\r\n
```

What I have tried:

- Adding the line

```
wsClient.Options.AddSubProtocol("mySubProtocolTwo");
```

Resulting in the same behavior. The subprotocols do not contain any forbidden characters according to RFC. If there was something wrong with the subprotocol name, the server would not respond with "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols".

Am I overlooking any obvious reasons why my client is throwing this exception? What are your suggestions for further debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was a mistake in the implementation of the websocket protocol on the server. It was a do it yourself implementation at a time when there were no reliable C++ websocket libraries.

Here is what [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-1.9) says regarding the subprotcol negotiation:

> The client can request that the server use a specific subprotocol
> by including the |Sec-WebSocket-Protocol| field in its handshake.
> If it is specified, the server needs to include the same field and
> **one** of the selected subprotocol values in its response for the
> connection to be established

So the client offers possible subprotocols in its request and the server choses one of them and puts it into the response header. In my case the server responded with all the available subprotocols which doesn't make sense, because then the client still doesn't know which one to use.

The C# websocket library interpretes the complete string of the *Sec-WebSocket-Protocol field* in the response header as one protocol name which ofcourse doesn't match with any of the requested protocols. Therefore it throws an exception.